# How to get the result of OverwritePrompt of SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get the value indicating that whether file has been overwritten or it is saved with a new name from a save file dialog. Here is my code

```
   var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog
                           {
                             OverwritePrompt = true, 
                             RestoreDirectory = true
                           };

   if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
      // it comes here if I save file with a unique name or if I select yes option from 
      // overwrite file propmt. I know I can check this with File.Exists() method. But saveDialog
      // object must contain some value that indicates that whether file is being overwritten or not. 
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The `SaveFileDialog` will not return when you click "no" in the overwrite prompt. If you click yes, or the file doesn't exist, it will return `DialogResult.OK`.

<s>How are you even comparing the `DialogResult` to true? What's your actual code?</s>

Oh, you're using WPF. Okay, what I said still stands. However, you don't have to use the `OverwritePrompt`. Instead, you can use your own dialog - you can use the `FileOk` event to show a dialog of your own, and handle its result any way you want (including returning a Cancel to the SFD).

Comment: @Ahmed Yeah, I've found out in the meantime. However, my point still stands - the dialog doesn't return unless you confirm the overwrite.

Comment: Yes, but dialog also returns if I save with a unique file name.